# Replace url with a variable and display object one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a file locally which has array of objects in my view i need it to be warped as a variable, on viewing the variable that array should be used

i tried this but i dont know its the right way could some one help me

```
var url = 'proj/array/arrayobject';
console.log(url);

var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
                $('div.comment-container').comment({
                  //here i should call that url and display object one by one with equal intervals

                })
            }, 1000);
```

could some one help me

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest to keep that file as JSON file having .json extension. It would make the file purpose more clear.

Secondly, You can use jQuery Ajax's `getJSON()` method to get data of that file and assign it to your local or global variable like below:

```
var myGlobalVariable = null;
$.getJSON("proj/array/arrayobject.json", function( data ) {
  myGlobalVariable = data;
});
```

Then, You can use your `myGlobalVariable` in your code. But, Make sure that you use it once you get data in it. For this you can use callbacks.

For your scenerio, Code will be like below:

```
var url = null;

function init() {
    $.getJSON("proj/array/arrayobject.json", function(data) {
        url = data;
        MyFunc();
    });
}

function MyFunc() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('div.comment-container').comment({
            // use url here
        })
    }, 1000);
}


$(function() {
    init();
});
```

Comment: could u check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583768/setinterval-on-load-json-object-one-by-one?noredirect=1#comment62653651_37583768

Comment: I just shown you the way how it can be achieved but I can not write code as you want. Rest you have to do.